# Floating point real at 32-bit precision

Tags: c#, floating-point

Please help me to convert byte array in to Floating point real at 32-bit precision using c# .
I am having a byte array ...
Floating point real at 32-bit structure is as follows
sign 1 bit
exponent 8 bits
fraction 23 bits
Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you know how a float is structured, what exactly do you want to know?

Comment: If native endianness is acceptable, you can use `Buffer.BlockCopy` to transfer bytes from a byte array to a float array.

Comment: @germi Assuming the OP talks about IEEE floating points, they don't actually understand how a float is structured. There are many tricky points, like exponent bias, NaNs and infinities, implicit 1 bit in front of the mantissa, unless it's a subnormal,...

Comment: @CodesInChaos You are right. I assumed the OP has some specifications which he follows. After all, I suspect this is a learning exercise not production code ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
byte[] bytes; //your byte array
float output = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
float floatArry= System.BitConverter.ToSingle(byteArray, startIndex);
```